# Want to seed with RAILS_ENV=production, but getting NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec::Core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, seeding

I have the following Rakefile:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
A4aa2::Application.load_tasks

if defined? RSpec
  task(:default).clear
  task default: :'spec:fuubar'

  namespace :spec do
    desc 'Run all specs in spec directory (with Fuubar formatter)'
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:fuubar) do |task|
      task.rspec_opts = [task.rspec_opts.to_s, '--color --format Fuubar'].compact.join ' '
    end
  end
end
```

I'm explicitly checking `if defined? RSpec`, but this doesn't prevent the following error:

```
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production --trace
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec::Core
/Users/josh/Documents/Work/Access4All/projects/a4aa2/src/Rakefile:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:209:in `in_namespace'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:147:in `namespace'
/Users/josh/Documents/Work/Access4All/projects/a4aa2/src/Rakefile:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/josh/Documents/Work/Access4All/projects/a4aa2/src/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
```

Do I have to check for `RSpec::Core` being defined, too? And whay is `RSpec` defined in production env anyway?

My `Gemfile` looks like this:

```
group :development, :test do  
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails' # RSpec for Rails
```

I don't want to put RSpec into the `:production` group, and that's the reason I'm checking whether `RSpec` is defined in the `Rakefile`, but it seems `RSpec` **is** defined in `:production` (although I'm only loading it in `:development` and `:test` groups), while `RSpec::Core` is not.

Comment: could you please add/share error log using --trace?

Comment: Have you checked with "gem 'spork', github: 'sporkrb/spork'" in your Gemfile?

Comment: What should this have to do with spork?

Comment: is the rspec gem within the test group in your gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `gem rspec` is within the `:test` group in `Gemfile`.

With rspec outside of `:test` group:

```
> puts "RSpec defined" if defined? RSpec
RSpec defined
 => nil
```

With rspec inside `:test` group:

```
> puts "RSpec defined" if defined? RSpec
 => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem altogether by checking for the appropriate environment, e.g. `unless Rails.env.production?`